# Demand Elasticity, Factor Substitution: Independent?

Tags: elasticity, production-function, elasticity-of-substitution, cost-functions

Given $ Y=f(K,L;\sigma) $, the effect on labor from a change in the price of capital can be gauged through a substitution effect and a scale effect:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial r}  & =\underset{Sub}{\underbrace{\left.
\frac{\partial L^{c}}{\partial r}\right\vert _{Y}}}%
+\underset{Scale}{\underbrace{\frac{\partial L^{c}}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial
Y}{\partial r}}}\\ \\
& =SH_{_{Labor}}\left(  \sigma+\eta\right)
\end{align*}
where $L^c$ is the conditional demand (the smooth movement along the isoquant).

This can then - as far as I can see - be also expressed as the sum of the factor substitution elasticity and the firm's elasticity of demand, weighted by the labor cost share.

But are $\eta$ and $\sigma$ independent of one another? If a firm can readily substitute factors in response to factor price changes, this will presumably impact its price elasticity of demand. Any thoughts?